# Make parent div cursor-pointer including child elements with inline styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline

I want to make an entire div `cursor-pointer` with inline CSS, but it currently only affects the whitespace around the child elements. I've tried `position` and `z-index` to no avail.

I do not and cannot have an external stylesheet.

```
<div className="cursor-pointer">
  <checkbox>
  <label>
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this without applying the `cursor-pointer` to every element? There's conditional logic as well so that would get pretty cluttered.

Comment: Do you mean to give each child the class name `cursor-pointer` or to apply the style `cursor:pointer` to the div?

Comment: Unfortunately, you will need to use CSS selectors or even javascript. You do have javacript tagged, is that a possible solution or did you just add that as a tag?

Comment: I want to put all className and onClick logic in the div rectangle to avoid having it in each element.

Comment: I'd be willing to consider JS/JSX options

Answer (score 1):

Since you allow the usage of JS, you could use `querySelectorAll` to select all child elements and apply the same class to it:

```js
let el = document.querySelectorAll('.cursor-pointer *');
el.forEach(ele => ele.classList.add('cursor-pointer'));
```

```css
/* just for demonstration purpose */
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor-pointer">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Label</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, this solution loops through the parent and children and applies the cursor directly to each element.

```js
let pointers = document.querySelectorAll(".cursor-pointer");



pointers.forEach(function(el) {
  let children = el.querySelectorAll("*");
  children.forEach(function(c) {
    c.style.cursor = "pointer";
  });
  el.style.cursor = "pointer";
});
```

```html
<div class="cursor-pointer">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>A</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I find it a really strange solution because this requires using custom CSS again. The whole JS approach is considered to not use custom CSS.

Comment: @tacoshy, yeah I updated my answer to be pure javascript.